# Avoid Sublime 3 hiding file tabs?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I migrated to Sublime 3 while ago a noticed a small difference compared to Sublime 2:

[image]

As you can see there, when I open some files, it starts to hide some files in the "background" and in order to come back to them is a little difficult. In Sublime 2, it would just reduce the width of each tab so that every tab is visible. How can I achieve this again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question:

In the User Settings file (Preferences → Settings), I had to add

```
"enable_tab_scrolling": false
```

That way the tabs are not hidden, and names are cut off instead.